# Resizing after choosing category

Tags: javascript, html, css

That code basically hides articles that won't match the category I choose from my select menu.
But then this happens.. Basically if I have only 3 images with matching category I will be left with a huge "blank" space on the bottom of the page.
[image: current state]

```
$(".filter").change(function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    var row = $('.portfolio-item'); 

    row.hide()
    row.each(function(i, el) {
     if($(el).data('type').split(' ').indexOf(filterValue) !== -1) {
         $(el).show();


     }
})

    // In Addition to Wlin's Answer (For "All" value)
  if ("all" == filterValue) {
    row.show();

  }


});
```

Is there anyway I can automatically resize the height of the section or div?
I already tried ( `overflow:hidden, resize:both` ) and some other CSS stuff but its not working...

Comment: could you offer more context on this? like maybe a sample html code as well with some css?

Comment: What is the problem in the image you attached -- is it the middle pic being at the bottom, or the other two pics being at the top? *Your question states there is a huge blank space at the page bottom, but that is not evident in the photo.* As Eugene mentioned, seeing the HTML/CSS would certainly help.